# Java: get InputStream out of an InputStreamReader

Tags: java, io, inputstream, inputstreamreader

Is it possible to get an InputStream out of an InputStreamReader instance?
If yes, how?

EDIT: i'm reading a binary file over network, so i need to read bytes, not chars.
I haven't found a way to do this with an InputStreamReader....

Comment: My answer is basically a long-winded "no" - but if you can give more context we may be able to give more guidance.

Comment: If you are sending a file, why should you want to read it?

Comment: sry, i want to read a binary file ;)

Comment: Well read it with an InputStream, why not?

Comment: i had to make some major changes in my sourcecode to get an InputStream.
luckily, they were not so big as i thought they would be. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without reflection, no... and I really wouldn't recommend using reflection here. (You would be very implementation-specific.)

Usually you shouldn't care about which implementation of `Reader` is being used at all, so you wouldn't even know it was an `InputStreamReader`... let alone try to get access to the underlying `InputStream`.

Comment: the problem is that i want to read Bytes, not Chars.
changing everything to an InputStream would be much work, so i hoped i can get one out of the reader

Comment: @user2422196: If you want to read binary data, you shouldn't have a `Reader to start with, almost certainly. Again, without any context about where this reader is coming from etc it's hard to help you, but it sounds like a situation you should just try to avoid.